# Font Awesome into WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, font-awesome

Someone tried to use Font-Awesome ([fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/‎](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)) into a `C#` / `WinForms` app?

Is supposed to be a font like any other, or not?

Comment: That link 404's. And also I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: Oops, sorry about the link... edited. Thx @user1189566 .

Comment: I used once, just remember to set as a `Resource`

Comment: No idea what your question means.

Comment: Hi @Tico!, thx by answer. Do you have any link? Into the winform app, I see the icons like in the web?

Comment: Hi @tnw! Font-Awesome is an `TTF` font with icons.(generally used in web projects with `BootStrap` and `CSS`). I want use that icons into an `Winform` app.

Comment: @Chapeti O_O that doesn't clarify your question at all...

Comment: Let me explain @tnw :-) 

Instead use image on your web projects, you can install Font-Awesome and use them vectors icons embedded the `HTML` code.

I want do the same, but, into an Winforms App.

Comment: Because the icons in Font-Awesome are pretty nice and scalable. (vectors)

Comment: Sorry, man. It was a long time ago, something like 3 months =/

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure those won't work in WinForms without using a webcontrol or something similar.  That appears to be a web/css font only.

[EDIT]
There appears to be some hope here:
https://superuser.com/questions/532556/how-can-i-use-font-awesome-in-photoshop-and-fireworks

Comment: Hi @Zippit ! That was my first impression too... but wanted to ask here to see if anyone had tried the same... ( I worked with Font-Awesome in web projects and I love )

Comment: Thx Zippit! we are one step closer... :-)

Comment: Font Awesome in Windows Form Application Here https://github.com/denwilliams/FontAwesome-WindowsForms

Comment: Here is a much easier to use drop-in class to use in a winforms project >  https://github.com/microvb/FontAwesome-For-WinForms-CSharp